# trying to install node.js and npm

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get Angular 2 up and running. The first thing it does is ask me to install node.js and npm.

So I've gone to https://nodejs.org/en/ and downloaded the msi, run it and gone through the install process.

Er... now what?

I go to my project folder and npm or sudo or any other node command is not recognized. Surely nodejs needs to be activated or something.

What gobsmacks me is that the nodejs site seems to assume I will just magically know the rest of the process. There's no instructions for actually installing or confiuring the thing. I guess I'm off to find some hand-rolled blog article from someone who's figured this out ahead of me?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Got confused when you talk about the "msi installer" and later on "sudo". If its windows, you should probably check the system variable %PATH% and include the node executables there.

Answer (score 0):

After installation of `NodeJS` you should have `npm` command with global access.
For initialization of project you would use `npm init` comand and follow instructions. If you don't have `npm` command in  the system i suggest you to check `NodeJS` installation. F.e., you can run `node -v` to see node version in the system.

Comment: Not until after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

After much googling, I found a set of instructions that suggested **a reboot is required** before nodejs will be available. True.

I've opened an issue to suggest this addition to the docs.

People often forget that there is little point in writing docs for those already familiar with a piece of software; it is the newbie that is most in need of direction.